# Do equipment abilities stack?

Tags: splatoon

If I have three items that all have the *Ink-Saver (Main)* ability, do I have significantly reduced ink usage or is it the same as if I only had one of those?  I suppose this question may not apply to all abilities (multiple *Recon* abilities likely provide no additional benefit), but it would be interesting to know if certain abilities like *Strength Up* stack, and if they do, do they stack linearly (increases each hit's damage by a certain amount) or multiplicatively (increases damage by a certain %).

Gear Abilities in question:

- Ink Saver (Main/Sub)
- Special Charge Up
- Special Duration Up
- Ink Recovery Up
- Quick Respawn
- Special Saver
- Bomb Range Up
- Tenacity
- Run/Swim Speed Up
- Defense/Damage Up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Judd's in-game tip, **abilities do stack, but are affected by diminishing returns**, which means that using two or three of the same ability will result in less than two or three times the effect of having one.

It's important to recognize the difference between primary and secondary abilities. Primary abilities appear as a big circle on each piece of equipment, which secondary abilities appear as smaller circle. There can be up to one primary and three secondary abilities per piece of equipment. According to the Splatoon Wikia:

> A secondary ability's value is around 1/3 that of the same primary ability.

Stackable abilities affect your stats multiplicatively, so each one that you wear will improve its respective stat by a certain percent. For example:

> The first Damage Up Primary applied gives a 9% damage boost, but 2 give ~8.25% each, and 3 give ~7.45% each.

The [Inkipedia](http://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Ability) and [Splatoon Wikia](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Ability) ability pages currently have conflicting information regarding the effects of individual abilities. You should view each to get an idea of how much of a boost each ability provides, but keep in mind that research is still ongoing.

Also, note that Tenacity cannot stack because it is only available as a headgear primary ability. All non-stackable abilities are only available as a primary ability on one type of equipment, so you never have to worry about wearing two non-stacking ones.

The 13 stackable abilities are:

- Damage Up
- Defense Up
- Ink Saver (Main)
- Ink Saver (Sub)
- Ink Recovery Up
- Special Charge Up
- Special Duration Up
- Special Saver
- Run Speed Up
- Swim Speed Up
- Quick Respawn
- Bomb Range Up
- Quick Super Jump

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all Equipment abilities stack but you get diminishing returns.
The diminishing interval depends on the Equipment. Generally the First Clothing effect will be about 8% then the second would be 5% and so on. So it ultimately depends on the Equipment

Comment: Your answer content should be about the answer.  Not a link to a wiki (unless it's where you're sourcing your answer from), or stating you're happy to answer more questions.

Comment: There definitely needs to be more on this. How bad are the diminishing returns? Is it the same for each effect? If there are known number,s those would be very helpful as well.

Comment: I used the wiki for future reference and for citing my source

Comment: Then you should make a more full list. Saying "generally" is not definitive. Additionally, there isn't a link in the post at all.

Comment: Where are you getting your numbers from?  On [the wiki's Gear Abilities page](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gear_Abilities), I don't see anything about diminishing returns which is why I asked this question